# iOS WKWebView Option Select Triggering Too Late

Tags: javascript, html, ios, xcode, wkwebview

I am using a WKWebview for a sign up form that exists on my web app.  There is a dropdown (option + select) to select a students 'degree'.

When you select the item, nothing happens.

When you press 'done' on the iOS keyboard, nothing happens besides the keyboard lowering

Finally, when you RESELECT the dropdown, the value updates correctly.
I verified that it was not just a visual issue but a value issue by placing some javascript:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.js.postMessage(`SELECTED `+this.value);
});
```

This confirmed my issue by showing a message in xcode, not when i select, not when i dismiss keyboard, but only when i RESELECT the dropdown a second time.

No clue whats causing it  or how to fix it.  Any ideas?
Heres a video: https://streamable.com/1sry8

Comment: This looks like a javascript problem. From the video, it looks like there's some more JS in there that could be causing problems. Could you share the rest of your code so we can take a look?

Comment: Wow i didnt even think of that, maybe one of my front end packages is preventing the default or something.  I will look into that and let you know!  Theres a lot of code so i have to search through to find relevant code to share

Answer (score 2):

Normally this should work.

Perhaps you could start with a minimal example and add more features and take a look when it breaks.

**Minimal Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select>
  <option value="viper">Viper</option>
  <option value="mamba">Mamba</option>
  <option value="cobra">Cobra</option>
  <option value="coastaltaipan">Coastal Taipan</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

**Calling from WKWebView**

[image: select WKWebView demo]